# Unable to access drawables from MapActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I am trying to get a drawable id using `R.drawable.mapPersonMarker`

These are the import statements:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

and this is the method I am accessing it from:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener {

    public void centreOnLoc(Location location, String title) {
        LatLng userLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.clear();

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLatLng).title(title).icon(R.drawable.mapPersonMarker));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLatLng, 18));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem:
The drawable resource name was "mapPersonMarker". File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore. Renaming the file to mappersonmarker fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mapPersonMarker).

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLatLng).title(title).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mapPersonMarker)));
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. The drawable resource is still not recognized